# correct way to run a unittest for reading a (yaml) file with pytest

Tags: python, unit-testing, yaml, pytest, fixtures

I created a function to read a config file in yaml-format. Now I want to add simple unittests with `pytest`. 
My approach would be to create both a `test_config.yml` (containing some data) and a `test_config_reader.py` (containing the actual tests, which are performed based on the data in `test_config.yml`).

Is this approach correct? Or do I need to create my "data" (i.e. the data in `test_config.yml`) as a fixture in `test_config_reader.py`?

To sum up: Is it okay to have non `test_*.py` files ("data"-files, like .yml, .csv, .pkl, ...) in the `tests/` folder of my project to use them in tests?

Comment: Yes, it is perfectly legal to have data files there

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, and I think I understand your approach. You could run Pytest from your YAML file, so it looks like this.

```
- id: run-pytest
  name: 'python'
  entrypoint: '/usr/local/bin/python'
  args: ["-m", "pytest"]
```

Comment: my question was answered in the comment of @FrankC